# Set all grid rows to auto xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin

Pretty simple question. I have a grid with over 10 rows. I want all rows to be set to auto, without having 10 separate RowDefinitions. I checked the documentation and it doesn't seem like there's a build in way to do so. How can I do this, or is having a row definition for **each** row necessary?

Comment: What are these grid elements that you want to place in these rows/columns?

Comment: They are mostly labels, and two (or more) rows have to have a click event.

Comment: why don't you just use a ListView in that case?

Comment: I have to have 2 labels next to each other (2 wide, x long), where all the right labels have to start from the same position.

Comment: I am still sure you can do that with a `ListView` and a `ViewCell`, actually this is exactly why you use ListView's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define all the rows. All the examples in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) envolve defining the row and its Sizing Strategy.

Comment: Well, defining the rows is the least bothering part, imho, having to count and set rows in the child elements, that's the sad part. Specially not being able to define names or such.

Comment: Yap. I need to add a click event to certain rows, so that'll be another thing.